# Tree analysis - CHAID

Tags: spss, cart

I am running a decision tree analysis, and the same predictor that forms the first core branch, reappears as an another branch further down the tree.

Could somebody explain me how this is possible? Or how I should interpret this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Decision trees make splits by finding partitions derived from the domain of covariates, so assuming you aren't using binary data this is not surprising behavior at all.

Consider a categorical variable, $x$, that has four levels, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'. The first split could be $x=A$. This means the 'False' portion of the split has $x$ which can still have values 'B', 'C' or 'D' so there are conceivably 2 more splits that can be made. In general for a categorical variable you can make $|x| - 1$ splits, where $|x|$ is the cardinality of the variable

In the case of continuous data, if all of your data points are unique you could make $n-1$ splits where $n$ is the number of data points.

Hope this clears it up a little for you.